# How to resolve importing tensorflow library

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, python-import

I am working on deep learing project so for that I wanted to import tensorflow library but when I run the code cell in the jupyter notebook it pops up the following error.

[Importing tensforflow library error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh8l7.png)

[Importing tensforflow library error screenshot continue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4OSc.png)

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py:469
    467 if hasattr(_current_module, "keras"):
    468   try:
--> 469     _keras._load()
    470   except ImportError:
    471     pass

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py:41, in LazyLoader._load(self)
     39 """Load the module and insert it into the parent's globals."""
     40 # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 41 module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     42 self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     44 # Emit a warning if one was specified

File ~\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127, in import_module(name, package)
    125             break
    126         level += 1
--> 127 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py:21
     15 """Implementation of the Keras API, the high-level API of TensorFlow.
     16 
     17 Detailed documentation and user guides are available at
     18 [keras.io](https://keras.io).
     19 """
     20 from keras import distribute
---> 21 from keras import models
     22 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input
     23 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models\__init__.py:18
      1 # Copyright 2022 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     13 # limitations under the License.
     14 # ==============================================================================
     15 """Keras models API."""
---> 18 from keras.engine.functional import Functional
     19 from keras.engine.sequential import Sequential
     20 from keras.engine.training import Model

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py:34
     32 from keras.engine import input_spec
     33 from keras.engine import node as node_module
---> 34 from keras.engine import training as training_lib
     35 from keras.engine import training_utils
     36 from keras.saving.legacy import serialization

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:45
     43 from keras.saving.experimental import saving_lib
     44 from keras.saving.legacy import hdf5_format
---> 45 from keras.saving.legacy import save
     46 from keras.saving.legacy import saving_utils
     47 from keras.saving.legacy import serialization

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\legacy\save.py:24
     22 from keras.saving.legacy import serialization
     23 from keras.saving.legacy.saved_model import load as saved_model_load
---> 24 from keras.saving.legacy.saved_model import load_context
     25 from keras.saving.legacy.saved_model import save as saved_model_save
     26 from keras.utils import traceback_utils

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\legacy\saved_model\load_context.py:68
     64     """Returns whether under a load context."""
     65     return _load_context.in_load_context()
---> 68 tf.__internal__.register_load_context_function(in_load_context)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'register_load_context_function'
```

I am expecting such explanation which can easily be understood and even a beginner can interpret the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have an incompatible version of `keras` installed.

Uninstall it with `pip uninstall keras` and try again.

The Keras API is available within Tensorflow itself if you need it; `from tensorflow import keras`.

Comment: Fixed the typo here...